# How to apply sed command on multiples files in directory with correct order?

Tags: sed

Hi I used below command to replace "*name*" and "*address*" in csv file with "*$$$$*".

```
sed -i 's/\(.*\)\("name"\|"address"\)\(,"\)\(.*\)\("\)/\1\2\3$$$$\5/g' *.txt
```

After giving this command if I give `ls -tr` its showing in reverse.
eg :
before sed output of `ls -tr`

```
a.txt,b.txt,c.txt
after sed commabd
c.txt,b.txt,a.txt
```

I want a command which will do the same operation and gives correct order.

Comment: This is because you use `ls` command with `t` --> "sort by modification time". Your files were modified, and hence the modification time also did, and now the order is different.

Comment: Actually, the files were not modified; rather new files were created and given the same name.  `-i` is incorrectly named because it does not modify files, but instead creates new ones.

Comment: yes I want to correct sed command which will modify my files in order of their creation or modification

Answer (score 0):

It looks perfectly normal.

ls -tr prints the files from the newest to the oldest. 
You have edited the files in alphabetical order so the newest file is the last edited c.txt.

If you want to see your files in alphabetical order, stop using "-tr" option on ls.

Comment: hi How i can edit the files with respect the creation time or modified time using same sed command

Comment: You can try to force the treatment order by using a loop.    for file in `ls -tr` ; do sleep 1; sed -i '....' $file ; done

Comment: any other way? without doing sleep.

Comment: you can get the former date of each file an reset it. Something like:  ls -tr ; do old_date=`date -r $file`; sed -i '....' $file ; touch -d $old_date $file; done